# When can I omit the word "есть"?

Tags: выбор-слова, порядок-слов

What's the difference between:

> у папы семь собак

and

> у папы есть семь собак

Are both sentences used? When can I omit *есть*? On a daily basis which of these would you use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this particular case it would not be an oversimplification to say that this forms are interchangeable and one can easily encounter in casual usage, say, `у меня есть две кошки` and `у меня две кошки`.

Keep in mind though that there still can be differences in usage Compare `у меня есть пистолет` and `у меня пистолет!`. First is more of a statement, an admission of the fact that one possesses a gun, so it's closer gotta gun "I have a gun". Second phrase is closer to notification, in some cases a warning if you mind (so this phrase can be translated as "I gotta gun!".

So in a hostage situation the Russian-speaking terrorist will most likely shout out: "У меня граната" rather than "у меня есть граната". Most likely but not necessarily.

Also the form "у меня + noun" can indicate possession in a figurative way, like in "у него грипп" or "у меня такая усталость". Phrases "у него есть грипп" or "у меня есть такая усталость" are non-existent.

Comment: Not objecting, but we can invent a context in which "у него есть грипп" would sound normal. "Доктор, у пациента нет гриппа!" - "Простите, коллега, но у него есть грипп." "Опишите свои симптомы, у вас нет такой усталости?" - "Да, у меня есть такая усталость."

Comment: It feels like when I say to you "У меня граната", the nuance is that that's all I care to say and you need to know about the situation. That nuance is absent in "У меня есть граната [и много чего ещё]."

Answer (score 5):

`Есть` is generally used where English applies the indefinite article to the object, 'a or an'. Where English would apply the definite article 'the' `есть` is usually omitted. For example:

У доктора есть телефон.       The doctor has a telephone
У кого есть словарь?          Who has a dictionary.

but:

У кого словарь?               Who has the dictionary

With numerals the word ectb is generally omitted.

In your example: у папы семь собок is generally used.

Comment: please don't spell Russian words in pseudo-cyrillic latin adaptation.